# Interactive SVG with JavaScript | embed or not embed SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to change the attribute of a circle in an SVG via javascript. When I have the SVG directly embeded in the HTML file, it works: 'kreis1' is changing color upon clicking a button. But when I have the SVG in an extra file (which I would like to have ultimatly when the SVG will have more than two circles), 'kreis1' doesn't react.

The is my SVG file, two circles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 43363)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<circle id="kreis1" fill="#8CC63F" stroke="#000000" cx="53.318" cy="55.5" r="50"/>
<circle id="kreis2" fill="#C44741" stroke="red" cx="138.786" cy="130" r="30" stroke-width="0"  
    onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','10');"
    onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','0');"/>
</svg>
```

... and here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<circle id="kreis1" fill="#8CC63F" stroke="#000000" cx="53.318" cy="55.5" r="50"/>
<circle id="kreis2" fill="#C44741" stroke="red" cx="138.786" cy="130" r="30" stroke-width="0"  
    onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','10');"
    onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','0');"/>
</svg>

<button onclick="getElementById('kreis1').innerHTML=changeColor()">Change!</button>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg">

<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            var htmlDocument = document;
            function changeColor()
            {
                document.getElementById("kreis1").setAttribute("fill", "blue");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

test.svg is a different document to the html document. Fortunately you can get the test.svg document via the contentDocument field on the `<object>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<circle id="kreis1" fill="#8CC63F" stroke="#000000" cx="53.318" cy="55.5" r="50"/>
<circle id="kreis2" fill="#C44741" stroke="red" cx="138.786" cy="130" r="30" stroke-width="0"  
    onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','10');"
    onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('stroke-width','0');"/>
</svg>

<button onclick="getElementById('kreis1').innerHTML=changeColor()">Change!</button>

<object id="object1" type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg">

<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            var htmlDocument = document;
            function changeColor()
            {
                document.getElementById("object1").contentDocument.getElementById("kreis1").setAttribute("fill", "blue");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert, but I have to ask again to clarify: What do you mean with 'test2.svg'? So I basically have two identical SVGs which I display to compare their behaviour: One is directly in the HTML document in the <svg> tag and the other one is in a separate file test.svg. I tried the html code you propose but now none of the two SVGs reacts to the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a typo. I realise you called the document test.svg The code I provided works in Firefox where I tested it. Note that I gave the `<object>` tag an id attribute, did you see that?

Answer (score -3):

It's a limitation of browser layout engines.  External SVGs can't be styled by CSS.  They have to be embedded in the HTML directly.  JavaScript does permit interaction via the object tag per Robert's answer.

If you'd like to go down the embedding route (in my opinion it is more flexible) I've developed a script to automate this embedding, I've got a couple of hours so I'll bundle it up into something reusable this morning and update the question when it's done.

EDIT: Here's the embedding plugin, with docs: http://sakurasvg.appsondemand.com.au/

Comment: It would be really nice if people would explain why they downvote - just a sentence would do.  I'm new here and I don't understand why this wouldn't be an appropriate answer.  Maybe not worthy of an upvote, but at the same time not downvotable either.  It allows the asker to keep the SVG in an external file and explains the pitfalls of linking externally.

It appears I was wrong about the "affected by JS" part (though correct about the CSS,) but a comment would have helped all of us, including others stumbling upon this question later, to learn.

Comment: External SVGs can be styled by their **own** CSS stylesheets and you could inject other CSS via javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that's constructive.  I still maintain that embedded SVG graphics have a place, primarily when you want to style multiple instances of them contextually, rather than having multiple versions of the same SVG file linking to multiple stylesheets.  Manual CSS injection with JavaScript is verbose and tightly couples markup, formatting and program logic, which is something that CSS was meant to reduce or eliminate in the first place.  I'd be interested to hear your thoughts. Risking this turning into a discussion though, so I'll leave it at that.